# Writing custom list using TextWriter

Tags: c#, list, textwriter

I have a class `Author.cs` as:

```
public class Author  
{  
   public Author()  
   { }  

   public int AuthorID;  
   public string AuthorName;  
   public List<Papers> Papers;  

   // ... rest of the methods...  
}
```

and another class `Paper.cs` as:

```
public class Paper  
{  
   public Paper()
   { }

   public int PaperID { get; set; }
   public List<int> CoAuthors { get; set; }
   public int VenueID { get; set; }
   public int PaperCategory { get; set; }
   public int Year { get; set; }  
}
```

I tried to print in a text file as:

```
TextWriter twObjClus = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(path, objClusterFilename));  
foreach (CurrentCluster curCluster in curClusters)
{
   twObjClus.WriteLine(@"ClusterID: {0}, ClusterSize: {1} \n",  
                         curCluster.GetClusterID(), curCluster.GetClusterSize()  
                      );
   twObjClus.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");  

   foreach (EvoObject eEvoObject in curCluster.GetClusterObjects())
   {
      Author eAuthor = (Author)eEvoObject.GetOriginalObject(); // it gives Object ID

      twObjClus.WriteLine(@"AuthorID: {0}, AuthorName: {1}, PaperID: {2}, Year: {3} \n",  
                            eAuthor.AuthorID, eAuthor.AuthorName,  
                            eAuthor.Papers.Select(p => p.PaperID),  
                            eAuthor.Papers.Select(y => y.Year)  
                         );
   } 
   twObjClus.WriteLine("\n\n");
}
twObjClus.Flush();
twObjClus.Close();
```

I'm getting right printing `Author_ID` and `Author_Name` in text file but not getting printed `Paper_ID` and `Year`, while instead both of these values, the statement that is being printed in text file is:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[DirichletProcessClustering.GraphData.Paper,System.Int32]

How can I print all these values in text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to evaluate the IEnumerable that is returned by:

```
eAuthor.Papers.Select(p => p.PaperID)
```

The string formatter is going to call `ToString` on the `IEnumerable` and that's why you're getting:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[DirichletProcessClustering.GraphData.Paper,System.Int32]

You could add an additional `foreach` statement and enumerate the above `IEnumerable` to write the paper IDs and years for the author like the following:

```
foreach (EvoObject eEvoObject in curCluster.GetClusterObjects())
{
      Author eAuthor = (Author)eEvoObject.GetOriginalObject();

      twObjClus.WriteLine(
          @"AuthorID: {0}, AuthorName: {1} \n",
           eAuthor.AuthorID,
           eAuthor.AuthorName);

       foreach (var paper in eAuthor.Papers)
       {
           twObjClus.WriteLine(
             @"PaperID: {0}, Year: {1}", paper.PaperID, paper.Year);
       }
}
```

Comment: Where I have to put this `foreach()` loop in my code?

Comment: You're writing to the same text file, aren't you? Then Yes.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `string.Format()` as I was not using it earlier

Comment: Yes you're right, you don't need the string.Format(). I update the code above to show you where to place the foreach

Comment: Thanks I guess it should work now, as my app takes some time to complete execution, after that will able to know whether it worked or not

Comment: One thing more want to know is: as single author may have multiple papers, so will the author ID and Name repeat in text file while printing papers with years ?

Comment: No, as far as the above code, the author ID and Name will show once before the list of papers with years. But of course, you can change it anyway you like.

Comment: I just have to put first writing statement inside that foreach loop we just used for ID and Name repetition

Comment: Off topic but do you know how to use `...` the waiter sign while some app is executing and we have to wait app to complete its execution and want to show some dots `...` or any other waiter sign (sometimes with time too) on console ? Not getting right keywords to search this. Did you understand my point @Timothy?